# OWASP 4.0.2 dependency-check-gradle plugin is not available

Tags: owasp

Owasp 4.0.2 plugin is not yet available in maven central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp/dependency-check-gradle).
When will be this available in the maven repository?

Comment: I have the same problem for my project in gradle 4.10: 
Plugin with id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' not found.

Comment: Owasp 4.0.2 is availble in maven now(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp/dependency-check-gradle/4.0.2).Please add the dependency compile "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:4.0.2" in build.gradle to get it.